# Permanently change the keyboard input source for an application in Big Sur

Tags: keyboard, input-source

I am needing to continuously change the input source for *Intellij-Idea* .  I have not even logged out: but just put the laptop to sleep and woken it up.  I do have the *Automatically switch to a document's input source* option checked:

[image]

But I have had to keep switching to the *usd2* layout by clicking here;

[image]

Actually I'd like to make that *usd2* the default for *everything* - but that seems to not be working and is a separate question that  I added a bounty for that here [Change the default keyboard input when logging into macOS Big Sur](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410580/change-the-default-keyboard-input-when-logging-into-macos-big-sur) .    Since that is not possible it seems that at least for one application - or for the files/projects within it - that this setting should be appropriate. But it it not working in my *Big Sur* macbook pro.

Comment: To me, the thread you bountied doesn't sound relevant to your issue. I think you need to get it working as the default for everything while logged in and then try the existing solution to the thread you bountied to get it working after reboot if you are using FileVault and have that problem. Otherwise, getting the default working may be all that is necessary. That having been said, as I'm not certain on the answer or setting a default, I'm posting a comment instead of an answer. Do you need the U.S. layout at all? If not, removing it so you only have the "usd2" layout might be effective...

Comment: Actually, I think I do know the answer.  I think you need to turn off "Automatically switch to a document's input source." That could switch the layout to U.S. for any program that it works with because all existing documents would most likely be set as U.S. documents.  If turning that off works, I can post it as an answer and you can confirm it.

Comment: @rpseu  I'm nervous to delete the default US layout. Can I undelete-it if necessary?

Comment: Technically, yes, you're only deleting it from the left, not from the machine.  The - on bottom would remove it and the + would add it back, but I don't think you need to try that anyway, see my comment from about the same time as yours.  Regardless, the only way I can see not being able to add it back is if a password was required and usd2 didn't allow you to input it.